# Open custom dialog on faceookLogin button?

Tags: android, facebook

**Hello everyone ,**

I am using facebook login in my application but i want to open alert dialog for term and cond. before opening the facebook login dialog. but on Facebook LoginButton click it is opening the facebook login screen only please give me some suggestions

**Thank You

Amit Sharma**

Answer (score 0):

Write alert dialog code in facebook login button's onClickListener. And then copy facebook login code to alert dialog's positive button (i agree or something like that).

Comment: i have add the code it showing but facebook login diloag overlap the my custom dialgo

Comment: Copy and remove codes which belongs to facebook login from that button. then paste it to the alert dialog's positive button. If it won't run again show your code.

Comment: sorry but it is opeing by default when i am click on facebokk Login button . It is not simple login Button it is FaceBookLoginButton

Comment: Okay it was my mistake, set facebookloginbutton's visibility to invisible. Then create your own Login button, now you can use performClick method in your positive button to call facebookloginbutton.